# Support of DLT binary for VS code extension DLT-logs

Tags: visual-studio-code, autosar, dlt-daemon

It is my first post and and do not have the reputation to create the required tag 'dlt-logs', Which is requested from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fishbone

mbehr1 I found your great tool at VS code extensions and I am looking forward to use it with all your nice features, especially the timing graph. The biggest issue I have... I got only DLTs in binary format. Could you add this, please!

Comment: always nice to have a puzzle finding the thing the question is about

Comment: HI @rioV8 ! Thanks for your comment. Would you be so kind to add the tag 'dlt-logs'? I hope your reputation is high enough. This would mbehr1 help to identify my request.

Comment: @LarsHanses I've added tag dlt-daemon, wiki for the tag is on review, (re-)tagged several questions